# if statement is not working inside of try and catch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I wrote a program to only accept even numbers and catch an exception if it is not an even number
when I enter an even number the code prints it but when I entered an odd number nothing happened

and whenever I try and add `else` red lines cover the whole block

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter number :  ");
int number = input.nextInt();
        
try{
    if(number%2 == 0){
       System.out.println(number);
    }
} 
catch(Exception  e){
    System.out.println("this input is not an even number");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The code in the `try` block never throws an exception. The `catch` block is only executed when an exception is thrown within the `try` block, so it will not execute.

Comment: There's no need to use try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd place to use an `Exception`. You **could** use an `Exception` to indicate the value is odd, like

```
try {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(number);
    } else {
        throw new Exception(String.format("Input %d is not even.", number));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("this input is not an even number");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**But**, you still need an `else`. And that would be a far more appropriate place to handle the odd value (no `Exception` neccessary). Like,

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println(number);
} else {
    System.out.printf("this input %d is not an even number%n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, the logic should be in an `else` block, not the catch block:

```java
try {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(number);
    } else {
        System.out.println("this input is not an even number");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Or some other more robust exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to *catch* thrown exceptions. But you rather should *throw* an exception. (And probably later catch it.)

```
 if (number % 2 != 0) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an even number: " + number);
 } 
 System.out.println(number);
```

There are two RuntimeExceptions most suited:

- IllegalArgumentException when the passed data is wrong;
- IllegalStateException when the state (calculation) is wrong.